# how to check which radio button (dynamically) is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm creating an online exam portal following is the code for displaying questions to candidates. I don't know how to handle the answers clicked by the candidates

```
$("input[name='hello']").click(function(){
    alert("you clicked on");
});
```

Radio buttons are dynamically created for 100 questions 4 each

Comment: What do you mean by __handle__?

Comment: just i'm displaying 100 questions 4 options each. and letting candidates to answer those questions. here i'm trying to valuate the questions checked by the candidate weather its right r wrong and finally displaying the score.

Comment: U can get selected radio button value by doing $('input[name=radiobuttonmae]:checked', '#formid').val()

Answer (score 2):

Try This -

```js
$('input[data-type=choice]').change(function() {
  var Question = $(this).attr('name');
  var Checked = $(this).attr('value');
  console.log('Selected Choice for ' + Question + ' is ' + Checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Log all Answers" onclick="logAllAnswers()">
<input type="button" value="Clear Log" onclick="console.clear();">
<hr>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>1. Select the answer for the first question.</legend>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q1" value="1">Option 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q1" value="2">Option 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q1" value="3">Option 3
    <br>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q1" value="4">Option 4
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>2. Select the answer for the second question.</legend>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q2" value="1">Option 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q2" value="2">Option 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q2" value="3">Option 3
    <br>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q2" value="4">Option 4
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>3. Select the answer for the third question.</legend>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q3" value="1">Option 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q3" value="2">Option 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q3" value="3">Option 3
    <br>
    <input type="radio" data-type="choice" name="Q3" value="4">Option 4
  </fieldset>
</form>



<script>
  function logAllAnswers() {
    $('input[data-type=choice]:checked').each(function() {
      var Question = $(this).attr('name');
      var Checked = $(this).attr('value');
      console.log('Selected Choice for ' + Question + ' is ' + Checked);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: data-type="choise" not supporting

Comment: What do you mean by not supporting. are you using jquery?-Check the results in the snippet it works.

Comment: in my editor notepad++ data-type="choise"  attribute displaying in black color i think its not supported.
Ya its working fine in snippet but in local host its not woring

Comment: `data-type` is just a custom data attribute which can vary [refer here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) , test the code in your browser. Can you show your code ?

Comment: Consider accepting my solution as answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider a value for each option

then use this to understand which one is clicked:

```
$("input[name='hello']:checked").val();
```

you can rewrite your code like this:

```
$("input[name='hello']").click(function(){
   var v=$("input[name='hello']:checked").val();
   alert("you clicked on"+v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a div with the questionWrapper class around every 4 boxes you could do something like this:

```
var collection = $(".questionWrapper");
$.each(collection, function(i, $questionWrapper, function(){
    //Do this for all the questions
    //Find the checked input (maybe use classes here...) and get its value
    var clickedAnswer = $($questionWrapper).find("input:checked").val();
    //Do something with the clicked var, maybe push it to an array and then compare the array to the solution
});
```